# Get file size given file descriptor in Go

Tags: file, go, operating-system

If given a path, I would use this to get file size

```
file, _ := os.Open(path)
fi, _ := file.Stat()
fsuze := fi.Size()
```

But if **only** given `fd`, how can I get the file size?
Is there any way in Go like this in C:

```
lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, does `fd` mean an integer file descriptor, as one would get from `open()` in C?

Comment: Yes. I get this fd by calling os.File.stat().Fd()

Comment: Yes, use [`syscall.Fstat`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Fstat) which is basically [`fstat(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html). Note that this is of course not portable to non-POSIX platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a new `*os.File` from a file descriptor using the [`os.NewFile`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#NewFile) function.

You can do it exactly the same way as in C, using [`Seek`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Seek)

```
offset, err := f.Seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
```

But since you have the `*os.File` already, you can call `Stat` even if it was derived directly from the file descriptor.

Comment: What will happen if I call os.NewFile, with the current file open. Does the new file a copy  of the current file?

Comment: @CubeyMew: It's the same file descriptor, so nothing happens. Even if you opened it with a new fd, opening a file does not copy it.

Comment: I want to use Open first to get a *File.   And later use Create(name string)(*File, error) to get the *os.File. Will this cause any effect on the file?
(I dont want to pass *os.File as parameter or make it as struct member)

Comment: @CubeyMew: opening a file has doesn't effect the file. If the file doesn't exist, the obviously `os.Create` will have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

try to get the file start

```
fileInfo, err := file.Stat()
if err != nil {...
}
files fileInfo.Size())
```